# Syntax error trying to see sys.dm_fts_index_keywords

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

Trying to run

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords( DB_ID('database_name'), OBJECT_ID('table_name') )
```

against the table with the index and I get a syntax error

If I run in on `master` I get

> Msg 30007, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Parameters of dm_fts_index_keywords and dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document cannot be null.

Answer (score 0):

I had to upgrade the compatibility level for the Database in order to be able to create the stoplist. Then all worked fine. Edetails here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2011/08/31/creating-stoplist-on-database-of-compatibility-80-90-in-sql-server-2008.aspx.